# How to provide binding arrow for the generated syntax?

Tags: macros, racket

Here is the full source code: https://gist.github.com/dannypsnl/d84af132553ab18328844bc1a41389a6

The question is can I refer `name` in `(-> a name)` to `Car-name`? In `->` form, it first gets the class of the instance, then generates a string `<class-name>-<field-name>` and converted it to syntax as `accessor`. Finally, it produces `#'(accessor instance)` to get the final result.

Generally, it means can I refer to the original definition from a generated syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending class names and field names like that is a fragile way of doing this. If I can suggest an alternate way, it would be better to use [`struct-field-info`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structinfo.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct-info..rkt%29._prop%7E3astruct-field-info%29%29) for that.

An example of how to use [`struct-field-info`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structinfo.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct-info..rkt%29._prop%7E3astruct-field-info%29%29):

```
(define-for-syntax (get-accessor type-id field-symbol)
  (define type-info (syntax-local-value type-id))
  ; both fields and accessors are reversed,
  ; but that's okay since they're consistent with each other
  (define fields (struct-field-info-list type-info))
  (define accessors (fourth (extract-struct-info type-info)))
  (list-ref accessors (index-of fields field-symbol)))
```

And to use it in your `->` macro:

```
(define-syntax-parser ->
  [(_ instance field-name)
   (define (class-of stx) ....)
   (define accessor-id
     (get-accessor (class-of #'instance) (syntax->datum #'field-name)))
   (with-syntax ([accessor accessor-id])
     #'(accessor instance))])
```

Now with that out of the way, your actual question:

#### How to provide a binding arrow

Assuming you want a binding arrow from the field name in the `class` definition to the same field name in the `->` expression, it's possible using syntax-properties `'disappeared-binding` and `'disappeared-use`.

The `class` definition will need an extra syntax property `'disappeared-binding` containing the `field` identifiers,

```
(define-syntax-parser class
  [(_ name field ...)
   (syntax-property #'(struct name (field ...))
                    'disappeared-binding
                    (stx-map syntax-local-introduce #'(field ...)))])
```

and the `->` expression will need `'disappeared-use` with its `field-name` identifier.

```
(define-syntax-parser ->
  [(_ instance field-name)
   (define (class-of stx)
     (car (syntax-property (local-expand stx 'expression '()) 'type)))
   (define accessor-id
     (get-accessor (class-of #'instance) (syntax->datum #'field-name)))
   (with-syntax ([accessor accessor-id])
     (syntax-property #'(accessor instance)
                      'disappeared-use
                      (list (syntax-local-introduce #'field-name))))])
```

Now, there are blue check-syntax arrows from the `name` in `(class Car name price)` to the `name` in `(-> a name)`, and from the `price` in `(class Car name price)` to the `price` in `(-> a price)`.

However, there's a purple-question-mark check-syntax arrow from the `price` in `(class Car name price)` to the `price` in `(-> b price)`, and the reason for that is in the function definition `(define (foo a b) (+ a (-> b price)))`, it's not certain what type `b` will be, so it doesn't really know whether `price` refers to the `Car` price or not.